# How do I add data to the maps app introduced in iOS 6?

Tags: maps, ios

Is there a way to add new data to the maps ecosystem introduced in iOS 6? For example, is there a way to add my own business to the map so everyone can find it? Also, can I add other point of interest like landmarks or a café that isn't on the maps to the publically visible maps?

If this is not possible, can I do the same thing just for me and share it with friends?

**Update**

When I look at the [attribution acknowledgements](http://gspa21.ls.apple.com/html/attribution.html) for that app I see that data is coming from overwhelmingly many sources. Some of them might even allow user contribution. If that works we just have to figure out which one to choose.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer works if Yelp is available in your country. Here's an alternative for the rest of us:

**How to add a location or business to iOS 6 Maps**

If an important location is missing in iOS 6 Maps you can use this process to suggest it.

- Launch Maps from the Home screen.
- Tap the page curl at the bottom right.
- Tap the text that says Report a Problem above the Print button,
  middle right.
- Tap location is missing.
- Tap Next.
- Drag the purple pin to the right location on the map.
- Enter the location information.
- Tap Send.
- Add any comments, if asked.

Apple will receive your suggested location, and if it meets their criteria, add it to the data base.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Maps application integrates data from Yelp (see the *Local Search* section of [Apple's description of Maps](http://www.apple.com/ios/maps/)), so I would guess that getting your business listed on Yelp would be a good start.

Find our more about how to [create a Business Yelp account](https://biz.yelp.co.uk/).

Comment: It seems that maps integrates the rating and review part only. The actual business data (location, adress, phone numbers etc.) doesn't seem to come from Yelp.